# Office api V2 authentication multiple resources in scopes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, azure-active-directory

I have successfully implemented the authorization flow but when I try to use scope from different api's like the office outlook task api and the graph calendar api I got an error message ***AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.***

**This doesn't work**

scopes=https://outlook.office.com/tasks.readwrite offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read
Write

**This works**

scopes=https://outlook.office.com/tasks.readwrite offline_access

or

scopes=offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read

Is it possible to request scopes from different api's at once or do I need two separated calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make two calls. Azure's endpoint doesn't support mixing scopes from different resources in one call.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Do you know if there are any plans to port the outlook task api into the graph (office 365 unified api)?

Comment: Yes, that is being worked on. I don't have a date, but hopefully it will be soon.

Comment: That's good news! Does that mean that at that point of time only one request is needed to obtain the access token since it's on the same resource

Comment: Is scope mixing still not supported? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Tasks are supported on MS Graph, have been for some time now. So you don't need to use both endpoints. Scope mixing is still not supported, and AFAIK never will be.